# Minimizing error of a formula in MATLAB (Least squares?)

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, linear-algebra

I'm not too familiar with MATLAB or computational mathematics so I was wondering how I might solve an equation involving the sum of squares, where each term involves two vectors- one known and one unknown. This formula is supposed to represent the error and I need to minimize the error. I think I'm supposed to use least squares but I don't know too much about it and I'm wondering what function is best for doing that and what arguments would represent my equation. My teacher also mentioned something about taking derivatives and he formed a matrix using derivatives which confused me even more- am I required to take derivatives?

Comment: There are literally dozens of tools to solve various regression problems in MATLAB, and as many more on the file exchange. However, teaching you how to do this, for someone who has no idea of what they are doing will take far more effort than most people are willing to put in, especially since you have told us very little about your actual problem. So any answer will need to be exhaustive, taking you from the ground up. I've seen entire courses taught about these problems. I've even taught one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you must be trying to solve is

Min u'u = min \sum_i u_i^2, u=y-Xbeta, where u is the error, y is the vector of dependent variables you are trying to explain, X is a matrix of independent variables and beta is the vector you want to estimate.

Since sum u_i^2 is diferentiable (and convex), you can evaluate the minimal of this expression calculating its derivative and making it equal to zero.

If you do that, you find that beta=inv(X'X)X'y. This maybe calculated using the matlab function regress http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html or writing this formula in Matlab. However, you should be careful how to evaluate the inverse (X'X)  see [Most efficient matrix inversion in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004148/most-efficient-matrix-inversion-in-matlab)