# using singular value decomposition (svd) in quadratic regression

Tags: matlab, regression, polynomial-math, svd

In order to do a quadratic regression on a rather large data set I would like to solve the following equation using svd(singular value decomposition):
B(nx1)=A(nx3)*X(3x1)
I am thinking to use matlab for that, any tips? the goal is to compute matrix X

Comment: Hard to say, since your question is too vague. First take a shot at it by yourself and see if you get stuck.

Comment: Interesting to see a reference to singular value decomposition for a non-linear, higher degree polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you call quadratic regression is actually the minimal square error regression. In this case the computation is very easy:

1) Multiply both left sides by A'(3xn) arriving to

A'(3xn)B(nx1) = A'(3xn)A(nx3) X(3x1)

2) Now multiply both left sides by the inverse of A'(nx1) A(nx3) arriving to

inv(A'(3xn)A(nx3))A'(3xn)B(nx1) =  X(3x1)

3) Now use svd to evaluate the inverse above, see [Most efficient matrix inversion in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004148/most-efficient-matrix-inversion-in-matlab)

See also [Minimizing error of a formula in MATLAB (Least squares?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235781/minimizing-error-of-a-formula-in-matlab-least-squares/15238828#15238828)